# Angular2 Adding providers dependency inside main.ts or component itself

Tags: angular

I have a very simple app in angular2 with three files:

```
main.ts
app -|
      app.component.ts
      app.service.ts
```

In my main.ts I have tried both these things:

```
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser"
import "rxjs/add/operator/map"

import { AppComponent} from "./app/app.component"

bootstrap(AppComponent)
```

and

```
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser"
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from "angular2/http"
import "rxjs/add/operator/map"

import { AppComponent} from "./app/app.component"

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS])
```

In the first case, since I haven't injected `HTTP_PROVIDERS`, I need to do in my app.component.ts:

```
/*Imports*/
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app/app.template.html",
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        AppService
    ]
})
/*Export*/
```

Is it the same to have injection (here HTTP_PROVIDERS) in the Component or in the boostrap ?

If so, what is the best practise ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same. According to the style guide prefer adding providers to `providers: [...]` of the root component instead of `bootstrap()`

See also

- https://angular.io/styleguide (search for "Providing a Service" or "Style 07-03"
- https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/702